# Insert a string in a single linked list

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I am trying to insert a string into a linked list of other strings.
The goal is to have the user enter whatever string they want (str_insert). Then, the user has to enter after which word they want to insert the string (new_node).

Unfortunately, the code manages to insert the word but it only ever inserts it in second position. The function used to insert the word is called insertion.

```
typedef struct dll {
    char data;
    int count;
    struct dll* next;
} dll;

typedef struct dictionary {
    dll * data;
    struct dictionary* next;``
    struct dictionary* prev;
} dictionary;

dll* entry(){
    char data = getc(stdin);
    if (data != '\n'){
        dll* curr = create_dico(data);
        curr->next=entry();
        return curr;
    }
    return NULL;
}

dictionary* insertion(dictionary *dico) {
    printf("Please enter the string you want to insert in your already 
    existing list: \n");
    dictionary * str_insert = malloc(sizeof(dictionary));
    str_insert->data = entry();
    str_insert->next = NULL;

    printf("Please enter after which word you would like to insert the 
    previous entry: \n");
    dictionary* new_node =(dictionary*)malloc(sizeof(dictionary));
    new_node->data = entry();
    new_node->next = dico->next;
    new_node->prev = dico;

    if (dico->next != NULL) {
        str_insert->next = dico->next;
        dico->next = str_insert;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a **dictionary** - not a "dictionnary" - one "n" is QUITE enough !

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work by implementing another function that compared the input with the already existing list.

Here is the final result:

```
dictionary* research(dictionary* dico, dll *search){
    dll *save = search;
    while (dico != NULL) {
        dll *tmp = dico->data;
        search = save;
        while(tmp->data == search->data && tmp->next != NULL && search->next != NULL){
            tmp = tmp->next;
            search = search->next;
        }
        if(tmp->data == search->data){
            return dico;
        }
        dico = dico->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void insertion(dictionary *dico) {
    printf("Please enter the string you want to insert in your already existing list: \n");
    dictionary * str_insert = malloc(sizeof(dictionary));
    str_insert->data = entry();
    str_insert->next = NULL;
    printf("Please enter after which word you would like to insert the previous entry: \n");
    dictionary* search =(dictionary*)malloc(sizeof(dictionary));
    search->data = entry();
    search = research(dico, search->data);
    if (search == NULL){
        printf("Sorry, this word isn't in the list.\n");
    }
    else{
        if(search->next != NULL){
            search->next->prev = str_insert;
        }
        str_insert->next = search->next;
        search->next = str_insert;
        str_insert->prev = search;
    }
}
```